# Factorizing $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I was solving questions related to polynomial factorization. I have learnt the remainder and factor theorems, and some basic identities.

There was a question like this one:

$$p(x)=x^3+8x^2+19x+12$$

The method we have been taught is to first find the factors of the last number, here it is $12$, so the factors are $\pm1$, $\pm2$, $\pm3$, $\pm4$, $\pm6$, $\pm12$. Then we have to substitute each of these values for $x$ till $p(x)=0$. Then, using factor theorem, we get a factor. For example, if $p(2)=0$, $x-2$ is a factor. Then, we use long division to get the product of the other two factors. Finally, we split the middle term and factor that expression.

I noticed that all of the answers were of the form $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$, which is equal to $x^3+x^2(a+b+c)+x(ab+bc+ca)+abc$. So, for the given question, if you find three integers such that $a+b+c=8$ (coefficient of $x^2$) and $abc=12$, can the factorization be simply written as $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$? In this case, it is $1+3+4=8$ and $1\times3\times4=12$, so factorization is $(x+1)(x+3)(x+4)$

I tried explaining this to my teacher, but she said that we must use the prescribed method of the NCERT book only.

So, is my method right? (I think so, but I'm not 100% sure) Also, is it necessary to confirm that the coefficient of $x$ is $ab+bc+ca$, or will that always hold true?

Comment: You also need to take into account the equation $ab+ac+bc=19$. Otherwise you could find numbers that give a factorization of another polynomial of the form $x^3+8x^2+Bx+12$. With this amendment, your method is correct, in principle. The problem is that in practice it is as hard to guess a solution of that system of equations as it is to guess the factorization all at once.

Comment: Your method is correct *if* all of the roots are integers, but if only one of them is an integer, the version you learned in class will find it, while your method won't.

Comment: In general $p(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ factorizes into $p(x) = a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$ where $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are roots. You may also be interested in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was going to type what you just said but you were slightly faster

Comment: If you haven't learnt complex numbers, you will soon discover that some polynomials resist to factorization in three binomials, like $x^3-1$.

Comment: @Pp.. Is there any example where $ab+bc+ca$ gives a wrong result, even if $a+b+c$ and $abc$ give right ones. I haven't come across one.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It may be tedious, but shouldn't it work for all rational numbers?

Comment: (2,2,2) and (8,-1,-1), for instance both have sum as 6 and product as 8

Comment: @JackYoon Thank you, I didn't notice.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Sure, I was assuming the first coefficient was $1$ since he factored it as $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$. And also assuming, since he is doing trial-and-error, that the coefficients were integers, or trial and error is much much harder

Answer (score 1):

Since $$P(-1)=(-1)^3+8(-1)^2+19(-1)+12=0$$
Therefore $x+1$ is one of the factors. After dividing $p(x)$ by $x+1$ we have
$$x^3+8x^2+19x+12=(x+1)(x^2+7x+12)$$
Since $$x^2+7x+12=(x+3)(x+4)$$ We are going to have
$$p(x)=x^3+8x^2+19x+12=(x+1)(x+3)(x+4)$$

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for an explanation of how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

So tell me if I am getting this right. You have 2 equations $a+b+c$ and $abc$ and you want $a,b,c$, which means you are using trial and error. If you use this in you exams, you surely won't get marks. You may think that what you were doing previously (factoring the constant term and substituting) was also trial and error, but it has a name)and you may know it- Rational Root Theorem. And this is how the Indian education system is. And now you may wonder why can't you use the third equation $ab+bc+ca$, now you have three equations and three variables. Try to solve them, you will get back again to the cubic equation.